# How to compare two inputText contains with onBlur and show a message

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have two inputText

```
<p:inputText id="numerOneId" />
<p:inputText id="confirmNumerOneId" />
```

and

```
<o:validateEqual id="equal" components="numerOneId confirmNumerOneId" message="the numers are not equal" showMessageFor="numerOneId" />
```

but the validateEqual just works whit a submit button, and I need it whit a blur event on confirmNumerOneId, how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `<p:ajax>` to the input which processes the both inputs *and* the validator and updates at least the message.

```
<p:inputText ...>
    <p:ajax event="blur" 
            process="numerOneId confirmNumerOneId equal" 
            update="numerOneIdMessage" />
</p:inpuText>
```

In case you're not using PrimeFaces, here's the `<f:ajax>` equivalent.

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:ajax event="blur" 
            execute="numerOneId confirmNumerOneId equal" 
            render="numerOneIdMessage" />
</h:inpuText>
```